# Sum date difference for all records excluding custom week days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found this useful query while searching by google:

```
SELECT
    SUM((DATEDIFF(dd, vacFrom, vacTo) + 1)
       -(DATEDIFF(wk, vacFrom, vacTo) * 2)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, vacFrom)='Friday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, vacTo)='Friday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, vacFrom)='Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, vacTo)='Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
FROM 
    MS_users_vacations 
WHERE 
    YEAR(vacFrom) = 2018
```

The use of it is for example: get the total vacation days of an employee for one year while excluding weekends if in case the vacation period include any, so **vacFrom** is the start date of the vacation and **vacTo** is the end date. But how to get the same result if the weekend days are custom? I mean if I want to sum the days between the date columns (vacFrom, vacTo) for all the table records BUT exclude weekdays like: Monday and Tuesday or any other days that I will pass by command parameters?

Comment: A date dimension table (also called a calendar dimension and sometimes a time dimension) is re-usable and many examples exist for creating and populating them. Some of the more thoughtful ones include case statements that populate flag columns for major US and international holidays; very useful when they occur on weekdays.

Comment: You need to explain the logic you want to implement, and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just two auxiliary integer variables, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, vacFrom) and 1+DATEDIFF(Day, 0, vacTo) - which I will name f and t - you can calculate all such values.
For example, the total number of days in a vacFrom-vacTo vacation will be t - f. To subtract the number of certain weekdays, you can calculate their number by using a difference of the results of two integer divisions. For example, t/7 - f/7 is the number of Sundays in the interval. In general, the number of "x-days" in the interval can be calculated as the difference

```
(t-x)/7 - (f-x)/7
```

where (modulo 7):

- x = 0 for Sundays,
- x = 1 for Mondays,
- x = 2 for Tuesdays,
- x = 3 for Wednesdays,
- x = 4 for Thursdays,
- x = 5 for Fridays and
- x = 6 for Saturdays (I prefer x = -1 instead).

This works, because the "date 0" used in the DATEDIFF expressions above is a Monday (which does not depend on some regional settings).
So, the number of days in a vacation interval excluding Sundays and Saturdays is

```
(t - f) - (t/7 - f/7) - ((t+1)/7 - (f+1)/7)
```

You will have to build a SUM over these values (as you did in your example), hopefully grouped by some userID (which you did not).

Following your question, if you instead want to exclude Mondays and Thursdays (1 and 4 in my list above), and you want to pass these two (which of Course must not be equal modulo 7) as parameters to the query, you could use the following T-SQL code (you might instead use a stored procedure or table-valued function to pass the two parameters):

```
DECLARE @par1 int = 1  -- Mondays
      , @par2 int = 4; -- Thursdays

SELECT userID
  , SUM((aux.t - aux.f)
      - ((aux.t-@par1)/7 - (aux.f-@par1)/7)
      - ((aux.t-@par2)/7 - (aux.f-@par2)/7)
    ) AS vacDays
FROM MS_users_vacations
  CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (DATEDIFF(Day, 0, vacFrom), 1+DATEDIFF(Day, 0, vacTo))
  ) aux (f, t)
WHERE YEAR(vacFrom) = 2018
GROUP BY userID;
```

You can also exclude only one or even more than just two weekdays, but if you substract all 7 possible differences, the results will be 0. :-)

Comment: This is an amazing answer and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you, @SherifRiad! :-)